# Create a dot mesh and drag over (limiting to) the surface of another mesh three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

In the code below I am creating a dot on the surface of mesh (intersecting points between camera and scene). These dots can be moved around using the `dragControls` option, but these dragged points can be moved outside the mesh as well.

I want to do the following:

1. When the `dragend` event is triggered I want my code to check if the drag release point is an intersect point between camera and scene.
2. If not, bring the dot to its original position where the `dragstart` event was triggered

```js
const dotOnClick = (event) => {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / container.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / container.clientHeight) * 2 + 1;
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
  var existingDot = dots.find(dot => dot.position.distanceTo(intersects[0].point) < 0.05);
  
  if (existingDot) {
    existingDot.material.color.set(0xFFA500);
  } else {
    var dotGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.005, 32, 32);
    var dotMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      color: 0x000000,
      wireframe: false
    }); // Black color
    var dot = new THREE.Mesh(dotGeometry, dotMaterial);
    dot.position.copy(intersects[0].point);
    scene.add(dot);
    dots.push(dot);
    dragControls = new DragControls(dots, camera, renderer.domElement);
    dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
      controls.enabled = false;
    });
    dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', function(event) {
      controls.enabled = true;
    });
  }
};
```